# Plotting already sorted histogram data stored in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, binning

I have a `.csv` file with histogram data in it, already binned & normalised which i read into a panda dataframe `df`:

```
Freq
0.4
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.01
0.05
0.1
0.04
0.05
0.05
0.02
0.08
0.10
0.03
0.07
```

I would like to plot this in a cumulative distribution histogram using matplotlib, but the pyplot.hist sorts the data and bins it again - which is not what I want.

```
plt.hist(df.loc[(data_tor['Freq'], cumulative = True)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: From the data, the binning in use isn't obvious. Once you have the binning that has been used to create the dataframe you may plot a bar plot from the bins and the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Freq'].cumsum().plot(drawstyle='steps')
```

[image]

And to fill under the curve:

```
ax = df['Freq'].cumsum().plot(drawstyle='steps')
ax.fill_between(df.index, 0, df['Freq'].cumsum(), step="pre")
```

[image]

Comment: Great - thanks. Supplementary question: Do you know how to fill under the plot?

Comment: @abinitio You are welcome! Use: `ax = df['Freq'].cumsum().plot(drawstyle='steps')`
`ax.fill_between(df.index, 0, df['Freq'].cumsum(), step="pre")`

Comment: Note for future readers: This answer is correct if the binning that has been used starts at -1 which is pretty uncommon.